# Get all loaded modules in DolphinDB

Tags: user-interface, module, dolphindb

How to check the loaded modules in DolphinDB? Or, which command can be used to access the modules executed in the GUI or the startup script (startup.dos)?

Answer (score 2):

I use `defs()` to check loaded functions, and use this query to get whether your module is loaded:

```
select * from defs() where name like '<module_name>::%'
```